# Can an activity based application have no activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-library, library-project

Assuming I have a shared activity class defined in a Library project, which does *not* change for any application using it and thus does *not* need to be subclassed, can I get a way with creating applications without subclassing this activity for them?

To better explain my question, say I have a single activity in a Library project:

```
public class LibActivity extends Activity {
 ...
}
```

And now I am creating an application using that Library project. Do I really need to create

```
public class AppActivity extends LibActivity {
 // totally empty!
}
```

Only so that the application have its own activity to be referenced in its own `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Can I get a way with a minimalistic approach, in which I subclass the activity only if I need to modify the library's activity core behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fully qualified answer:

Yes, an activity based application **doesn't have to** derive an activity from the library's activity. The application simply uses the library's activity verbatim, unmodified.

Yes, I can get a way with a minimalistic approach, in which I subclass the activity **only if** I need to modify the library's activity core behavior.

I have been able to verify this with an `AndroidManifest.xml` that is *identical* in both the library and the application. It would be interesting to see whether some of this redundancy can be eliminated. I will experiment with this and report back.

**UPDATE:** Sure enough, it is possible to create a perfectly running application in which the only activity is defined in the library and the library's  `AndroidManifest.xml` doesn't have any `<application>` or `<activity>`! This is possible if the application's `AndroidManifest.xml` has them.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference library Activity classes directly from your application AndroidManifest.xml. Just specify the fully qualified name like so `android:name="com.example.LibActivity"`

Comment: Thanks +1 for being the only one trying to answer this. I will post the exact answer shortly (for the benefit of all) but I can tell you already that I didn't even need to specify the fully qualified for the Activity in the library.

Comment: Clarification: I didn't need to specify the fully qualified name for the Activity in the library because both the library and the application shared the **same exact package name**. If they have different package names (which they should), then of course @sparkymat's advice must be taken.